# How to flip an image in javascript on a html canvas?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game in pure js with an HTML5 canvas. My player is a cube but its weapons are images. I have successfully drawn the image on top of the player:

```
var gun = document.getElementById('gun');
c.drawImage(gun,this.x,this.y);
```

but I want it to flip the gun image vertically when the player turns. I have tried changing scaleX when the player turns:

```
if(this.l == true){
    this.x -= this.speed;
    gun.style.transform = 'scaleX(-1)';
}
if(this.r == true){
    this.x += this.speed;
    gun.style.transform = 'scaleX(1)';
}
```

but nothing happens, please help
the HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CUBE</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
    <img id="gun" style ='display: none;' src="gun.png">
    <script src = 'index.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add the canvas html to your question?

Comment: @dalelandry sure you mean the html file right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `css` for scaling I would go for the following solution:

```js
function goLeft() {
    gun.flipX = true
}

function goRight() {
    gun.flipX = false
}

function drawGun() {
    if(gun.flipX) {
        ctx.drawImage(gunImg, -gun.x -gun.w,gun.y,gun.w,gun.h)
    }
    else {
        ctx.drawImage(gunImg,gun.x,gun.y,gun.w,gun.h)
    }
}
```